# Probability for continuous uniform distribution from $0$ to $10$

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ has a continuous uniform distribution on the interval $[0, 10]$. Calculate: $Pr(X+\frac{10}{X}>7)$.

Comment: Hint: Where is $f(x)=x+\frac{10}{x}$ greater than $7$?

Comment: What have you tried? What relevant probability topics have you been studying recently?

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

$x+\frac{10}{x}>7$

$x>0$

$x^2+10>7x$

$x^2-7x+10>0$

$0≤x<2$ or $5<x<∞$.

Well, we know your random variable is $[0,10]$, and is uniform along that interval. So, it must be $\frac{2}{10}+\frac{5}{10}=0.7$

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use the hint of @JeppeStigNielsen. Another is to
Use the transformation method for PDFs, and then find the
distribution of $Y = X + \frac{10}{X}$ and integrating
to find $P(Y > 7),$ being careful to note the support of $Y$.
Using the transformation method for CDFs would involve
expressing the desired probability as 
$$1 - P(Y \le 7) = 1 - P\left(X + \frac{10}{X} \le 7\right)$$
and solving the RHS to get the answer in terms of $X$,
which amounts to the first method for practical purposes.

You have given no clue as to what you are studying at this point,
so I don't know what approach the author/instructor has in mind.

Below is a simulation based on a million $X$'s sampled from
$Unif(0,10).$ You can use the simulation result (accurate to two or three places) for comparison with your analytic answer from one of these methods.

```
x = runif(10^6, 0, 10)
y = x + 10/x;
mean(y > 7)
## 0.700893
```